# Is there a way to highlight the whole row, copy it to a new place then add a new line and reformat its original place?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, paste

I'm having a few teething problems with a code I'm writing.  I'm relatively new to coding and don't understand it 100% but i can normally work it out. Im creating an events tracker so the rows indicate places on an event that people can book onto, when someone cancels i want tot to show they are cancelled but open up the slot again so someone else can book on.

I keep receiving either error 1004 or error 242 on the code below. What i'm trying to achieve is when i press the button the selected cell will highlight thee entire row,highlight it red and insert a new blank row below, copy the original row to a new destination (the last row of a dynamic range lower down on the same tab).

I've fiddled around loads with it already (activecell.entire row alyouts, setrng= layouts etc) so its probably really wrong and messed up - which is why i need some help sorting it out.

```
Sub CANCEL()
Dim rgCopy As Excel.Range
Set rgCopy = Range(Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row), Range("IV" & 
ActiveCell.Row).End(xlToLeft)).Select 
rgCopy.Copy (Range("_cancel3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))


ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
ActiveCell.EntireRow.ClearContents

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

End Sub
```

It feels really close but that im just missing that last bit. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think the following code should help you achieve your goal.

```
Sub CANCEL()
 Dim rgCopy As Range
 Set rgCopy = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":IV" & ActiveCell.Row)
 Dim dynamicRange As Range
 Set dynamicRange = Range("A20")
 rgCopy.Copy
 dynamicRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 rgCopy.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 rgCopy.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
 rgCopy.Offset(1, 0).ClearFormats
 rgCopy.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi RCL thanks for your help. The dynamic range is alreasdy set up and called _cancel3 i changed out the "A20" for _cancel3 and it simply replaced the first line with the copied cells. Ive tried changing it to 

    Set dynamicRange = Range("_cancel3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

but its bringing up an error - any advice?

Comment: Hello again - i seem to have fixed it - there was a propblem with my dynamic range  - all fixed now thankyou for your help!

Comment: Congrats glad I could help :)